# First bash script - Enter root password only once

Tags: shell-script, password, gksu

I wrote a small bash script. It needs root password.

There are two commands only, both of which need the permission. So, currently I must enter the superuser password **twice** - I don't want that.

I linked the script to desktop. And I'm executing it from desktop I mean.

My effort, which does not work:

```
gksu -u root "iptables -D INPUT 7 && iptables -D INPUT 6"
```

Comment: What's about running script by sudo? I mean that you will make a simple bash script & run it instead of direct commands running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `sh` to combine two commands into one:

```
sudo sh -c 'iptables -D INPUT 7 && iptables -D INPUT 6'
```

Of course making a script will be more convenient if it's not a one-time thing.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would write a script and place it in `~/bin` or some other directory in $PATH, and then have a desktop icon that executes `sudo <script_name>`. There's lots of ways to do this, this is my preferred method:

```
mkdir ~/bin
editor ~/bin/myscript
```

Then write your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -D INPUT 7
iptables -D INPUT 6
```

Save it and make it executable:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/myscript
```

And at last make a desktop shortcut that executes the script:

```
editor ~/Desktop/myscript
```

containing:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Applicaton
Name=Myscript
Comment=My script that does something cool
Icon=help-info
Terminal=false
Exec=bash -c "sudo ~/bin/myscript"
```

You will then be asked for the sudo password only once.

Comment: You may have to use gksudo instead of sudo, I don't have gksudo on my system to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sudo -v` to "refresh" the permissions. You could use this in a background loop while the script runs. (I adapted this from somewhere else ages ago, but I've forgotten where.)

```
sudo_done="/tmp/sudo.finished"
sudo_me() {
 while [ ! -f $sudo_done ]; do
  sudo -v
  sleep 5
 done &
}

stop_sudoing() {
  touch $sudo_done
  sleep 7
  rm $sudo_done
}

sudo_me &
# Your script here.
stop_sudoing &
```

Also, if it's not a GUI program, `gksu` is unnecessary, and `sudo` is fine.

Comment: Why the downvote?